# Javascript / jQuery Find Text duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, duplicates

How would you approach finding duplicates in a text document. Duplicates can be a set of consecutive words or sentence. Sentence not necessary ending with a dot. let's say page contains a document of 200 lines of which 2 sentences are identical, we want to highlight those 2 sentences as duplicates when "check duplicate button" is clicked.

Comment: Let's say. `<body><p>....text.......</p></body>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question — here's an idea on how I'd do that probably: http://jsfiddle.net/SaQAs/1/ — **Not anyhow optimized!**

```
var text = $('p').text(),
    words = text.split(' '),
    sortedWords = words.slice(0).sort(),
    duplicateWords = [],
    sentences = text.split('.'),
    sortedSentences = sentences.slice(0).sort(),
    duplicateSentences = [];


for (var i=0; i<sortedWords.length-1; i++) {
    if (sortedWords[i+1] == sortedWords[i]) {
        duplicateWords.push(sortedWords[i]);
    }
}
duplicateWords = $.unique(duplicateWords);

for (var i=0; i<sortedSentences.length-1; i++) {
    if (sortedSentences[i+1] == sortedSentences[i]) {
        duplicateSentences.push(sortedSentences[i]);
    }
}
duplicateSentences = $.unique(duplicateSentences);

$('a.words').click(function(){
    var highlighted = $.map(words, function(word){
        if ($.inArray(word, duplicateWords) > -1)
            return '<span class="duplicate">' + word + '</span>';
        else return word;
    });
    $('p').html(highlighted.join(' '));
    return false;
});

$('a.sentences').click(function(){
    var highlighted = $.map(sentences, function(sentence){
        if ($.inArray(sentence, duplicateSentences) > -1)
            return '<span class="duplicate">' + sentence + '</span>';
        else return sentence;
    });
    $('p').html(highlighted.join('.'));
    return false;
});
```

---

**Update 1**

This one finds sequences of identical words: http://jsfiddle.net/YQdk5/1/ From here it shouldn't be hard to e.g. ignore any kind of punctuation at the end of fragments when comparing — you'd would just have to write your own version of an `inArray` method.

```
var text = $('p').text(),
    words = text.split(' '),
    sortedWords = words.slice(0).sort(),
    duplicateWords = []
    highlighted = [];

for (var i=0; i<sortedWords.length-1; i++) {
    if (sortedWords[i+1] == sortedWords[i]) {
        duplicateWords.push(sortedWords[i]);
    }
}
duplicateWords = $.unique(duplicateWords);

for (var j=0, m=[]; j<words.length; j++) {
    m.push($.inArray(words[j], duplicateWords) > -1);
    if (!m[j] && m[j-1]) 
        highlighted.push('</span>');
    else if (m[j] && !m[j-1])
        highlighted.push('<span class="duplicate">');
    highlighted.push(words[j]);
}

$('p').html(highlighted.join(' '));
```

**Update 2**

My regex-fu is weak, but this (pretty messy!) version seems to work okay: http://jsfiddle.net/YQdk5/2/ — I'm pretty sure that there might be a better way of doing this, but for now I've got to leave it alone! :D — Good luck!

**Update 3**

Thinking about it, I don't think that the code from the previous update is any good. That's why I've removed it. You can still find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/YQdk5/2/
The main point is to use a regex to match words, something along the lines of:

```
/^word(\.?)$/
```

Comment: +1 for the efforts. I had a similar concept for finding duplicate words. Sentence is the issue here. In your case it must end with a dot for it to be recognized. So if we have the same 2 sentences in different areas, but one if not followed by a dot, it will not be recognized.

Comment: I guess it's more of a word sequence than a sentence then, isn't it ;) .

Comment: yes exactly. Looking for ideas and best way to approach this.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, good approach. I like what you did in the third update although i can be improved, but overall a good start.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution that uses suffix tree:

```
function SuffixTree(text) {
    var regex = /\b\w+/g;
    var words = text.match(regex);
    var wave = [];
    var words_l = words.length;
    if (words_l == 0) return false;
    this.tree = this.node("", false);
    for (var i = 0; i < words_l; ++i) {
        var x = words[i] + "_";
        wave.push(this.tree);
        var wave_l = wave.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < wave_l; ++j) {
            var y = wave[j];
            if (typeof y[x] != 'undefined') y[x].count++;
            else y[x] = this.node(words[i], y);
            wave[j] = y[x];
        }
    }
}

SuffixTree.prototype = {
    dummy: {count: 1},

    node: function(word, num, parent) {
        return {
            count: 1,
            word: word,
            parent: parent
        };
    },

    duplicates: function(h) {
        this.dups = [];
        this.bypass(this.tree, h, 0);
        var l = this.dups.length;
        this.dups.sort(function(d1, d2) { return d1.depth > d2.depth ? 1 : -1; });
        for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            var d = this.dups[i];
            this.dups[i] = { s: " " + this.sentence(d.a) + " ", depth: d.depth, count: d.a.count };
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            var d = this.dups[i];
            console.log(i, d.s);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            var d = this.dups[i];
            var fl = true;
            for (var j = i + 1; j < l; ++j) {
                if (this.dups[j].s.indexOf(d.s) != -1) fl = false;
            }
            if (fl) h(d.s.substr(1, d.s.length - 2), d.count);
        }
    },

    bypass: function(a, h, depth) {
        if (a.constructor != Object) return;
        var fl = true;
        for (var i in a) {
            if (i == 'parent') continue;
            var b = a[i];
            if (b.count == a.count) fl = false;
            this.bypass(b, h, depth + 1);
        }
        if (fl && a.count > 1) {
            this.dups.push({ a: a, depth: depth });
        }
    },

    sentence: function(a) {
        var s = a.word;
        while (a = a.parent) {
            s = a.word + " " + s;
        }
        return s;
    }
};

var text = "This is a text with some duplicates: words, sentences of different length. For example here is a duplicate word. This sentence has some duplicates. But not all of us can find clones.";

var T = new SuffixTree(text);
var h = function(s, c) {
    document.write(s + "[" + c + "]<br/>");
};
T.duplicates(h);
```

1) Split the input text to the array of words.
2) Build the suffix tree.
3) Find the longest suffixes of the tree.
4) Remove sentences that are contained in others (i.e. remove "is" that is a part of "this is a").

You can change the regular expression to take into account html tags.

I hope this helps you.

P.S. `h` is the callback for found duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You're javascript contains references to a javascript library named jQuery.

You are not including this in your HTML, and thus it will fail.
You can include it via [jquery cdn](https://code.jquery.com/)

And todays tip: Use the developer tools in your browser. In the console you can see what parts of javascript that fails.